# Is there a way for ExceptionHandlers to output an argument when an unchecked exception is thrown?

Tags: java, spring, debugging, exception, unchecked

```
@Component
public class Fetcher {
    private void sendGet(String url) {
        someMethodThatCanThrowUncheckedException();
    }
}

@Controller
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private Fetcher fetcher;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/content"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getContent(@RequestParam(value = "url", required = true) String url) {
        fetcher.sendGet(url);
        return "Success";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleUncaughtException(final Exception exception) {
        return "An internal error has occured trying to fetch url: " + url;
    }
}
```

I would like a way to be able to output the variable `url` in `handleUncaughtException`. However, since the exception comes from another class `Fetcher`, is there any way I can know what the `url` parameter was that likely caused this unchecked exception?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe I can't just store the `url` as a field in `TestController`, because I'm calling the `/content` endpoint concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set the `url` in the request attributes and retrieve it in your `@ExceptionHandler`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/content"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getContent(@RequestParam(value = "url", required = true) String url, HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setAttribute("url", url);
    fetcher.sendGet(url);
    return "Success";
}
```

And retrieve it

```
@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
@ResponseBody
public String handleUncaughtException(final Exception exception, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String url = (String) request.getAttribute("url");
    if (url != null) 
        return "An internal error has occured trying to fetch url: " + url;
    else 
        return "something else";
}
```

You should probably make the attribute key something constant.

Comment: thanks! I've decided to use request.getParameter("url") instead

Comment: @Popcorn That will work if `url` came from the request parameters. It will not work in any other case.